# Cannot broadcast to Facebook via libRTMP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rtmp

My app uses libRTMP for live streaming to RTMP servers.  It works well for many servers. For example, if I wish send a video stream to twitch.tv, I start by using the following URL:

rtmp://live-ams.twitch.tv/app/my_stream_key

After it my video is put to the server.

But it doesn't work for Facebook.com.  If I create URL by using their instructions ( https://www.facebook.com/facebookmedia/get-started/live ):

rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/xxxxxxxxxxx?ds=1&s_l=1&a=yyyyyyyyyyy

After enter it to my program, I get the error in the log: " Auth Token Validation Failure".   Why? The other apps, as a ManyCam and XSplit, work with that URL well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We must enter the following url:

> "rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/[your_stream_key]&api_token=[your_api_token] tcUrl=rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/[your_stream_key] swfUrl=rtmp://rtmp-api.facebook.com:80/rtmp/[your_stream_key] flashVer=FMLE/3.0\20(compatible;\20FMSc/1.0) live=1"

I hope it'll help you to save your time.